# OAUTH 2 - Box API - Python - HOW DO I INJECT THE JSON TOKEN?

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, box

I am trying to play with the Box API, I have set up the local SDK, authorized the API token, and I think I have this mostly correct, my only issue is that the developer toke (which is a .JSON file on ht desktop does seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
from boxsdk import OAuth2, Client

oauth = OAuth2(
  client_id='s2dfw23wer3s6b1t4grd5grv',          #don't worry these are fake
  client_secret='pHgPObYY2342f2f3HIHVvPOb',     #don't worry these are fake
  access_token='YOUR_DEVELOPER_TOKEN',          #currently im just using the root path is that wrong
)
client = Client(oauth)
root_folder = client.folder(folder_id='0')
shared_folder = root_folder.create_subfolder('NEW FOLDER')
shared_link = shared_folder.get_shared_link()
```

Comment: So are you passing a filename as the access token?

Comment: Ive never interfaced with an API before so im guessing that is wrong lol.

Comment: No worries, first time for everything :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are passing an access token to an API, it needs to be a physical token. It is not uncommon to use config files for this if tokens are static, you'll just have to read the token from the file. Say the file looks like this:

```
# mytoken.json
{
    "token": "kdvnajdfhaoejfskjvnb",
}
```

You would load it in like this:

```py
from boxsdk import OAuth2, Client
import json

def load_token_from_file(token_path):
    with open(token_path) as fh:
        # get your token from the token key
        token = json.load(fh)['token']

oauth = OAuth2(
  client_id='s2dfw23wer3s6b1t4grd5grv',          #don't worry these are fake
  client_secret='pHgPObYY2342f2f3HIHVvPOb',     #don't worry these are fake
  access_token=load_token_from_path('path/to/token.json'), # now you're getting the token from the file itself
)
```

Comment: okay! it authenticates! when Im making calls, I believe I have to designate who is making the request, in this case its OAUTH which spits out an error.                        'Request "POST https://api.box.com/2.0/folders" failed with UnicodeEncodeError exception: UnicodeEncodeError('latin-1', 'Bearer \u200e\u2068/Users/jpearson/Desktop/251014362_3kgolmf9_config.json', 7, 9, 'ordinal not in range(256)')'

Comment: That sounds like your token is not formatted correctly. What are you passing in as the token?

Comment: I added the code above in the edits so you can see it. Would it be helpful to look at the JSO?N file?